# code::blocks creates a .dat file but it's empty

Tags: c, codeblocks

I've been writing a code of random walk in c language. The program compiles perfectly and I can see the results in the code::blocks console. But I need to create a file .dat for import its data and make a plot of "iterations number vs the mean of the square displacement" in qtgrace.

The problem is that code::blocks creates the .dat file but it's empty. I don't know why this is happening.

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>

FILE *fp;

int c,i;//c is the number of walkers and i is the iterations number
double x,r; //x is the displacement and r is a random number
double s[2000]; //array for the displacement squared
int n[10]; //array for the number of walkers

double main(){
fp=fopen("caminata.dat","w");

    printf("Write the iterations number i=");
    scanf("%d",&i);
    printf("Write the number of walkers c=");
    scanf("%d",&c);


    n[10]=0;
    s[2000]=0;

    for (int j=0; j<c; j++){ 

        //srand((long)time((time_t *)(NULL)));
        x=0.;

        for(int k=0; k<i; k++){

            r=rand()/(double)RAND_MAX;

            if(r<=0.5){

                x=x+1;

            }

            if(r>0.5){

                x=x-1;

            }

        s[k]=s[k]+x*x;//
        }

        }

    for (int k=0; k<i; k++){//mean of the square displacement
            s[k]=s[k]/c; //divided by the number of walkers
            printf("\n%d    %lf",k,s[k]);
            fprintf(fp, "\n%d    %lf",k,s[k]);
        }
        fclose(fp);
    }
```

This is  the plot I must obtain

[Random_Walk: iterations number vs the mean of the square displacement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0yIe4.png)

Comment: What were the values did you have enter? (trying to produce the same error)

Comment: Hi!. 10 walkers and 2000 iterations. The program asks you to write them in the console

Comment: Your code's working fine and everything's printed in the file. It's either related to file writing permission or the IDE itself.

Comment: I don't know if it influences my problem but, I'm using the MinGW compiler. Can it be related to that? How can I fix the issue with the writing permission?

Comment: Check the return values of `fprintf()`. What are they?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see 2 times `k<i` in for loops but I don't see `i` being defined.
There is 1 chance out of 2 that value is defined to a negative value, in which case it makes sense your file is empty.

Comment: Hi! I've defined "i" as an integer and the program asks the user to write it in the console. "i" is the iterations number desired.

Comment: I most have overlooked that.

I did notice this. You have `double s[2000];` and later on `s[2000]=0;`. Similar thing for `n[10]`.
If the maximum index is always size - 1, so `s[2000]=0` is writing outside the array!
If you want to initialize to zero you could do `memset(s, 0, sizeof(s));`

Comment: Oh. Thank you very much. I did it for both arrays and now it's working!

Comment: It's a common mistake. Your compiler should have warnded you about it.
Thank you for clicking the up arrow next to my answer to indicate that it was the solution.